Fake contract but was verefy as 0 danger
I was able to swap twice but someohow user blocked windrwas...can someone help me? https://etherscan.io/tx/0x03a3624a3f8ce062497a567a7411d9e0b39e2d62fb584ca589f89e47c8e7d91c
